# Rails routes formatted params in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my routes:

```
match '/car-rentals(/:address)' => 'search#search', via: :get
```

I can visit:

localhost:3000/car-rentals/montreal

Shows all available cars for Montreal.

When I enter: `localhost:3000/car-rentals/Montreal Quebec`

My URL becomes `localhost:3000/car-rentals/Montreal%20quebec`

I would like it to be: `localhost:3000/car-rentals/montreal-quebec`

I tried using `to_param` in my model.

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{address.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

Any other ways to achieve this?

Also worth mentioning. When I stick `binding.pry` in `to_param` and reload the page, it doesn't stop the process, so not getting there.

```
  def to_param
    binding.pry # on page load, not getting here
    "#{address.parameterize}"
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pick up on it. Why isn't `to_param` and `parameterize` working?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not getting to `to_param`, I updated the question

Comment: Have you restarted your Rails server after overriding the `to_param` method? I feel as though the `to_param` way of setting the URL should work.

Comment: Yes, I have, don't worry about it, shipped it without it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several gems that generate slugs for SEO friendly urls.

I've used https://github.com/norman/friendly_id in the past and it worked fine. It also has very helpful documentation.

There is also this: https://github.com/Sutto/slugged